# Overriding module method on Django start

Tags: django, python-module, django-middleware

I use `django.contrib.messages` module to create flush messages. These messages can be shown in different blocks on the page, depends on extra tag:

```
messages.error(request, 'Error message', extra_tags='form')
```

I have default tag named 'global' and I need to add it in new message if no extra_tags set. So I wrote middleware to wrap `django.contrib.messages.add_message()` method on application start:

```
class Initialization:
    def __init__(self):
        self.init_messages()
        raise MiddlewareNotUsed

    def init_messages(self):
        add_message_method = messages.add_message
        def add_message_wrapper(request, level, message, extra_tags='', fail_silently=False):
            if not extra_tags:
                extra_tags = 'global'
            add_message_method(request, level, message, extra_tags, fail_silently)
        messages.add_message = add_message_wrapper
```

I see that `init_messages()` method is called, but when I call `django.contrib.messages.add_message()`, it is not wrapped with `add_message_wrapper()`.

Where is my fail?

Comment: Did you call `messages.add_message()` or `messages.error()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just add the "startup code" into `settings.py` or in `views.py` instead?

If all you are doing is adding a default value `"global"` whenever `extra_tags` is empty, you could also do that within the page template while rendering your messages:

```
{% if not message_obj.tags %}
    // Use "global"
{% else %}
    // Use {{message_obj.tags}}
{% endif %}
```

This can also be done inside your view code:

```
storage = messages.get_messages(request)
for message in storage:
    if not message.tags:
        message.tags = "global"
storage.used = False
```

See the Django docs for more info https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/#expiration-of-messages